# Difference Between MemFree and MemAvailable

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-management

Using Ubuntu 14.02 and running the command cat /proc/meminfo, I get the following:

```
MemTotal:        1007796 kB
MemFree:           64248 kB
MemAvailable:      64876 kB
```

I'd like to know the exact difference between MemFree and MemAvailable. Also any hints as to how I could more efficiently use system resources would be appreciated. I have a new laptop on order, but for the moment, I'm developing on a machine with 1Gb of RAM.

Note: I was running two terminals and eclipse at the time of the command, so you can see how it's tough to multi-task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Linux cat/proc/meminfo - what do all  those numbers mean?](http://superuser.com/q/521551/53953)

Comment: @KenWhite I saw that post as well. It explains what MemFree is, but not MemAvailable.

Comment: Did you also see that it was at [su] (where it belongs) and not here (where it does not)? :-) This site is for programming questions, and yours is about interpreting the output of a command line utility. (Actually, as your question is specifically about Ubuntu, I'd suggest [ubuntu.se] instead as the best place to ask.)

Comment: Apologies, I've seen some questions asking for clarifications of similar topics here. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Those are typically older posts from before the other sites came into existence. :-)

Comment: In my experience `MemAvailable` is a bit on the safe side. Many times when the system is near memory pressure a new user mode program can reserve at least that amount of memory without problems. I'm currently running kernel 4.15 and it seems that the amount of `MemFree` is more than can be actually reserved by new processes. If a new process tries to acquire `MemFree` amount of RAM, the system performance will go through the floor and latency will go to seconds instead of of milliseconds. It's not uncommon to see `MemAvailable` at zero on my workstation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rik van Riel's [comments when adding MemAvailable to /proc/meminfo](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773):

> ***/proc/meminfo: MemAvailable: provide estimated available memory***
>
> Many load balancing and workload placing programs check /proc/meminfo
> to estimate how much free memory is available.  They generally do this
> by adding up "free" and "cached", which was fine ten years ago, but is
> pretty much guaranteed to be wrong today.
>
> It is wrong because Cached includes memory that is not freeable as
> page cache, for example shared memory segments, tmpfs, and ramfs, and
> it does not include reclaimable slab memory, which can take up a large
> fraction of system memory on mostly idle systems with lots of files.
>
> Currently, the amount of memory that is available for a new workload,
> without pushing the system into swap, can be estimated from MemFree,
> Active(file), Inactive(file), and SReclaimable, as well as the "low"
> watermarks from /proc/zoneinfo.
>
> However, this may change in the future, and user space really should
> not be expected to know kernel internals to come up with an estimate
> for the amount of free memory.
>
> It is more convenient to provide such an estimate in /proc/meminfo.
> If things change in the future, we only have to change it in one
> place.

Comment: Will memfree == memAvaialable - if I run execute drop cache? For example 
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Comment: The link and quote are helpful.  A brief layman's interpretation would also help.

Comment: `man proc` includes the documentation for /proc/meminfo.

Comment: See my [laymen's interpretation in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71256266/1048186)

Answer (score 5):

*MemAvailable*: The amount of **memory**, available for starting new **applications**, without swapping.

*MemFree*: The amount of **physical RAM**, in kibibytes, left unused by the system.

Though we read English, the definition is not clear enough to users. Is MemAvailable refer to software or even user space? What does **applications** mean? Other than swapping, **hugepage** included? What about **directmap**? And **kernelpage**?

It is again anology problem, that is to say "The name that can be named is not a Constant Name."

Back to reality, what we really want to know is how to calculate or at least which is bigger.

ARM-based sample

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       1053938048 kB
MemFree:        1050967832 kB
MemAvailable:   1047631704 kB
Buffers:           14972 kB
Cached:           125416 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
```

Intel-based Sample

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       65960628 kB
MemFree:        37493412 kB
MemAvailable:   64537424 kB
Buffers:         5899700 kB
Cached:         19890832 kB
SwapCached:         8672 kB
```

Sadly after openning two monthly-pay servers, the problem is more complex, is CPU related?

OK, back to English again. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/

*free*: not costing or charging anything

*available*: present or ready for immediate use

So take the tables as an example for memory. When we go to restraut, sometimes there are free tables but they are not available; and there are available tables but no more free tables.

Comment: free ram is actually left by the kernel, not registering that memory for use.

Answer (score 3):

**Free ram** is actually left by the kernel, not registering that memory blocks for use.
**Available Memory** is the registered memory blocks with kernel, and ready to use immediately.

**Verdict**: We should consider ***Available Memory*** as free ram. Extra room to run more application.

Answer (score 1):

Using MemAvailable is a better estimate than using MemFree.  On current implementations, `MemAvailable` can be significantly larger than `MemFree` if there is a large page cache.

As Rik van Riel [commented when adding MemAvailable to /proc/meminfo](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773), it is best for the kernel to estimate how much free memory is available (which it does through MemAvailable) since the way of calculating this may change as the kernel implementation does.

In the commit linked above, MemAvailable is calculated as

```
MemAvailable = MemFree - low water mark + min(page cache/2 + low water mark) 
                   + some other reclaimable stuff
```

If `page cache/2` is smaller than `low water mark`, this could be less than MemFree.  But we must bear in mind that different kernels may have different implementations because, as Rik van Riel reminds us, each kernel knows how much space it has free best.

So use MemAvailable to see how much memory a new process could use.

`man proc` tells us:

> ```
> MemAvailable %lu (since Linux 3.14)
>     An estimate of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping.
> ```

This is a layman's explanation of [TheBeast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019697/1048186).

Comment: One suggestion for your answer. MemAvailable can be less than MemFree. If there is no more reclaimable memory (like if it's all ballooned out when using a hypervisor), then `MemAvailable = MemFree - low water mark + min(page cache/2 + low water mark)` which is certainly less than MemFree. I've personally seen MemAvailable show as 0 while MemFree shows 3200000 KB.

Comment: @wxz That's a nice example, and I've edited my answer to correct for this situation. But even then, MemAvailable is the better estimate, right?  Because even then, there is in fact no memory that can be allocated (at least right away), right?

Comment: When you say "better" do you mean better for using it as an estimate for free memory to use for running new user-space programs? Then yes! If you have some MemFree but 0 MemAvailable as I've seen, you can't start any new process.

Comment: @wxz Well yes, but I'd also like to know what the best way of estimating memory available for *existing* processes is as well!

Comment: My understanding is that for existing user-space process, they can only access MemAvailable. Any leftover MemFree is only for kernel operations. But might want to verify elsewhere to be sure that my understanding is correct.

Comment: @wxz -  can even existing process use the memory from memavailable if it needs more memory as time goes on ? asking because at many places, it is mentioned that memavailable is memory estimate which can be used to start `new`  process. but can existing process also use that memory from memavailable which is `not intersecting with memfree` (i.e. in caches, etc and needs to be reclaimed)

Comment: @Yusuf Yes. You can write a small C program to test this. Have your program sleep for a few seconds to start so you can note the starting MemAvailable. Then use `malloc` to request some large amount of memory (make sure to write to the memory if `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` is 1 to make sure it's the memory is actually allocated) . You should see MemAvailable decrease because of your existing process.

Comment: @Yusuf If you do write such a program, please consider posting it as another answer to this question (with some discussion of how it does answer the question.) Then be sure to link to that question from here!

Comment: @wxz & Josiah - i am not well-versed in low-level languages like C which deal with memory using malloc, so will leave it for now

Comment: To the passerby versed in C and malloc... please feel free to pick up what wxz and I suggest!