# How to make a query to check memory available in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to make a query using PromQL to check memory available (RAM).

Is the query below correct to check memory available **without cache and buffer?**
I worte the query regerring to [the link](https://acloudxpert.com/working-with-memory-metrics-from-node-exporter/)

```
# Node Exporter : Memory used >= 75% (Without Cache, Buffer)
(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemFree_bytes)/ node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 <= 25
```

I used the query below before, but the result didn't look like the answer I was looking for

```
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes/ node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 <= 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is correct. I use this:

```
100 - 100 * (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) >= 75
```

Comment: Hi Oliveria, Thank you for the answer.
Can I ask one more question?
What's the difference betwwen `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes ` and `node_memory_MemFree_bytes`?
When I used `100 - 100 * (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) >= 75`, The result on my server was around 85.
However, when I used `100 - 100 * (node_memory_MemFree_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) >= 75`, The result was 95. 
I expected `node_memory_MemFree_bytes` would result in a less value than `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes`, but it didn’t.

Comment: No, MemAvailable is always less than MemFree. MemFree is the amount of physical memory left unused by the system and MemAvailable is the amount of memory available for starting new applications, without swapping. See more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869297/difference-between-memfree-and-memavailable.